# Unity does not open when i try to open a project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I already tried reinstalling unity, installing .net, and installing visual c++

But none of that worked

(info-log.json https://notepad.ltd/4h6hr44m)

It also gives me a (0x000007b) error when i open unity.exe, but that must be because i opened it without a project

derHugo stated that it is because of 'ERROR.PROJECT.PATH_NOT_FOUND' as in the path of the project is missing, but i tried recreating the project and i also couldn't find the default project for unity 2d

Big update thanks to derHugo, The reason this doesn't work is because of the missing  project  files, unity doesn't create the default files for some reason and i tried everything... :(

BUT when i tried making the folder,  it said, not proper project... this means the folder is correct  and derHugo is correct, now we need to find out how to let  it create the project

Comment: `ERROR.PROJECT.PATH_NOT_FOUND` ... did you rename or move your project folder? It is expected to be in `C:\Users\Admin\Helping Hand` .. does this path exist? do you have access to this path?

Comment: I cant find the folder, but this is a new project, so there must be no reason... I tried deleting and making the project again , but to no avail

But opening unity.exe gives me "The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b)"